# How to use JMESPath to query AWS CLI RDS instances by DBInstanceIdentifier

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-cli, jmespath

I need a list of RDS DBInstanceIdentifier that match the String "foobar" in their name. I found many solutions with exact match, but not substring matching. My approach looks as follows:

I get a list of all DBInstanceIdentifier using:

`aws rds describe-db-instances     --query "DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier][]"`
which looks like

```
[
    "machine-001-alice-abcdefg", 
    "machine-002-bob-abcdefg", 
    "machine-003-foobar-abcdefg"
]
```

On the list I apply a filter like in the [last example of the JMSES Tutorial](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#next-steps)

`aws rds describe-db-instances     --query "DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier][]|[?contains(@,'dev') =='true']"`

If I change the statement to != I get the full list, so it seems I have the filter statement wrong.

Comment: What is your actual goal? Do you wish to list the `DBInstanceIdentifier`, but only for instances that have `dev` within the `DBInstanceIdentifier`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. 9bO3av5fw5 provided a solutionthat I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`true` needs to be backticked not quoted and then the backticks need to be escaped it seems - different shells may vary.

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier][]|[?contains(@,'dev')==\`true\`]"
aws rds describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier][]|[?contains(@,'dev')!=\`true\`]"
```

You can also omit the comparison to true but I couldn't invert this successfully

```
aws --profile pollen-nonprod rds describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier][]|[?contains(@,'dev')]"
```

(I'd normally do this sort of thing with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) but that's a different solution rather than necessarily a better one)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I know jq but I need a solution that works with no dependencies. Thanks!